# How to find the joint gaussian pdf using the linearity of expectation?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

A random process $Y_n=X_n+\frac{1}{5}X_{n-1}$, given that $X_n$ is a gaussian random process with a mean $E[X_n]=10$ and autocovariance $C_X(n_1,n_2)=e^{-3|n_1-n_2|}$.

From a previous part of the question, I already calculate the mean, variance, autocorrelation and autocovariance of $Y_n$. And now it asks me to find the an expression of the joint gaussian pdf of $Y_3$ and $Y_5$, and gives me a hint to use the linearity of expectation to solve it.

I get that the joint gaussian pdf is calculated using $\frac{1}{2\pi |C|^\frac{1}{2}}exp[-\frac{1}{2}(\vec x-\vec m)^T\vec C^{-1}(\vec x-\vec m)]$, but how do you calculate it using the properties of the linearity of expectations?